# SDWebImage appears to be using http GET method with .refreshcached instead of a HEAD method

Tags: ios, swift, caching, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` for caching images in a Swift/iOS app, and we are using it in some places with `.refreshCached` option enabled.

We're using Amazon s3 for images which has support for the "Last-Modified" header on the request.

My understanding is that with `.refreshCached` enabled `SDWebImage` should check the http header with a HEAD request to check to see the last modified date in the header, THEN if the date has changed, it can perform a GET method on the URL to get the data, saving bandwidth.

However when I inspect the calls that the app is making (using `CocoaDebug`), I only see the GET methods in the log, meaning even when the image is cached we're still fetching all the image data.

On subsequent views where the images are visible, I see that images load instantly, implying the cache is working, but I still see the full GET methods and no HEAD method in the log.

Does `SDWebImage` support this HEAD followed by GET flow or am I doing something wrong or otherwise misunderstanding?